# Qml: Difference be onPropertyChange and setting a particular value based on property using a formula)

Tags: qt, qml

Suppose I have QML item `A` like so:

```
Item A{
    property real value
    property real position: value*100
}
```

As you can see, I have two properties, one of which depends on the other. The same result can be achieved by using `onPropertyChanged`. For example:

```
Item A{
    property real value
    property real position
    onValueChanged:{
        position=value*100
    }
}
```

Obviously the first approach reduces extra lines of code. But, there will be cases where the right hand side of the formula could get complicated. Based on the necessary actions required when `onValueChanged` is triggered, the first approach may or may not be viable.

What could be the performance difference between the two?

Comment: You wouldn't need _onValueChanged_ just to set/change the value of _position_ ..

Comment: Both of these examples are the same. Both of them use concept of "binding". But the first one use native QML binding while in the second example you do the work instead of QML. There is no problem to assign a value returned from function: `property real position: someFunction()` in which the complex calculation will be performed

Comment: As I know the difference is that if you change `position` in code outside of definition like `a.position = 3` that will collapse the binding. And then even if you will change `value` the `position` will never change again. Second binding will solve this.

Comment: @AmirRasulov That's a good thought. Due to parent properties being public, they are susceptible to change during usage, which causes loss in binding. Thank you for bringing this up.

Comment: @MohammadKanan It is not a question of whether the approach is required or not. I was interested in knowing in what ways one could be more viable than the other, along with performance considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways might be applicable in different situations.

The first way is the "QML Way". QML is meant to be a declarative language, which means that you basically just declare the relations between properties and objects. For this they introduced the property bindings.

The main reason for that is, to keep the files easily readable and understandable.

In some cases you will struggle with only bindings - let's say you have a property

```
property int lastPressedButtonId
```

This is hard to bind to something. You might succeed with arbitrarily crazy constructs. But here you would improve the readability when you have the buttons set that property imperatively using signal handlers and JavaScript.

The doc states that simple bindings can be optimized upon translation. So this would be strongly in favor of using the binding.

Another thing is the posibility of *@folibis* - you can bind it to a function. Here I can't tell you much about the performance difference. I guess it is little since you will likely use this method only when it can't be transformed into a QV4/Compiled Binding. And after all, all bindings are implicitly transformed into JS expressions anyway.

You can also bind to a C++ Q_INVOKABLE/slot. I think here you need to pass all properties whose changes shall trigger an update as parameters to the slot. I haven't tried that in a long time, since I usually prefer to instead publish a Q_PROPERTY from C++ with the complexly calculated value to QML.

Here you will find an interesting blog series, dealing with the internals of property bindings and their optimizations:

https://www.kdab.com/qml-engine-internals-part-2-bindings/
http://www.kdab.com/qml-engine-internals-part-3-binding-types/

---

**To Summarize:**

- You should choose the most readable approach. In most cases, that are bindings.
- You should strive to have dependencies between properties simple. Than the bindings can also be optimized
- Use JS when using bindings would needlessly complicate it. E.g. when you are in fact react to an event or a signal that does not reflect a property change.

Comment: Thank you for talking about various considerations.I believe this is a comprehensive answer.